# is there any unit upper triangular matrix in $GL_n(F_p)$ such that the following holds

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields, general-linear-group

Let $U_1$ be the group of $n\times n$ upper triangular matrices with 1's down the main diagonal (called unit upper triangular matrices) over $\mathbb{F}_p$ , which is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G=\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ .

I want to know that is there some fixed matrix $M_1\in U_1$ such that $NM_1N^{-1}\not\in U_1$ for all $N\in\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)-U$ , where $U$ is the group of all upper triangular matrices in $\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ .

If such matrix $M_1$ exists, I could show that the normalizer of $U_1$ in $G$ is contained in $U$ , i.e., $\mathbf{N}_{G}(U_1)\subseteq U$ . Conversely, we can easily check that $U\subseteq\mathbf{N}_{G}(U_1)$ . Then since $U_1\in\mathbf{Syl}_p(\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p))$ , the equality $\mathbf{N}_{G}(U_1)=U$ implies that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G=\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &|G:\mathbf{N}_{G}(U_1)|
 \\=&|G:U|
 \\=&\frac{|\mathbf{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)|}{\left|\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}\right|^n\cdot|U_1|}
 \\=&\dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(p^n-p^k\right)}{(p-1)^n\cdot p^{n(n-1)/2}}
 \\=&\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(1+\sum_{m=0}^{k}p^{m+1}\right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
I have tried to find some matrix $M_1$ which can be easily calculated by matrix multiplication and satisfies the properties as mentioned above, like the matrix defined as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \ \ 1&0&\cdots&0&1\ \ 
 \\&1&&&0\ \ 
 \\&&\ddots&&\vdots\ \ 
 \\&&&1&0\ \ 
 \\&&&&1\ \ 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
but I am not sure that whether it is as desired.

Comment: The obvious $M_1$ to try is the full Jordan block $J_n(1)$.  Think about the filtration by $\ker (J_n(1)-I)^k$s.

Comment: That matrix won't work. If you conjugate it with a matrix $N$ that other wise looks like the identity matrix, but it has a single 2x2 block of the form
$$\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0\cr}$$ somewhere along the diagonal. Conjugation by $N$ (its an elementary matrix) amounts to first interchanging two rows and then the corresponding columns. I would try adding ones next to all the diagonal entries. User10354138 seems to have that idea already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your counterexample! I have checked that $M_1$ conjugated by such $N$ is actually an element in $U_1$ in the case that $n=4$ . But I am also curious about the motivation for considering such $N$ , or is there a name for this kind of matrices $N$ ? They seem like some special involutory matrices.

Comment: I was guided by a special case of [Bruhat decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition). In the case of $GL_n$ it says the following. If W denotes the group of permutation matrices, i.e. matrices with a single 1 on each row and column, and zeros elsewhere, then 
$$GL_n=\bigcup_{w\in W} UwU.$$ There is also a well developed theory of the intersections $U\cap wUw^{-1}$ in terms of how complicated the permutation $w$ is, and that's where the example comes from. I think of the matrix given by @user10354138 as tailored to work for all the simple permutations (=2-cycles).

Comment: (cont'd) I think the general theory implies that if an example $M_1$ works for all 2-cycles, it works for all $w\in W$, and (by the Bruhat decomposition) for all $N$, but I won't bet the family fortune on that. A beer, may be :-).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for providing this. You're so knowledgeable. But I only know a little about this theory: the group of permutation matrices is isomorphic to $S_n$ . I think I should learn more about linear algebra since I was usually confused with problems about classical groups.